# cscope: How to navigate back with cscope in Vim?

Tags: vim, cscope

I'm a linux newbie and recently using **Vim** & **Cscope** reading kernel source code.

Here is a line in my vimrc for finding C symbols

```
nmap <F2>s :cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>:cw<CR>
```

press `F2+s`, selecting a row in the **quickfix List**, the whole edit view switch the target symbol, and I don't know how to navigate back to the place where I start the query.

I didn't find anything helpful in `:cs help` and online tutorials. Does Cscope have function like `ctrl+t` in CTags for backward navigation?

Comment: I am able to use `<c-t>` with commands such as `:cscope find g {symbol}`. I have `'cscopequickfix'` set to nothing however which may explain the behavior. Also all of Vim's help can be accessed via `:help` (`:h` for short). Cscope's help can be found via `:h cscope`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your cscope navigation should have set the *alternate file*, `<C-^>` then takes you back to the original file. This works only one level. For multiple levels, you can use the *jump list* and its `<C-O>` command.